# How to connect playstore payment gateway inside app in Android?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I am creating an app which is free for few modules and I would like users to pay for other modules that are available in this app. I don't want the users to pay and download the full version from playstore. Instead I would like the users to use my app to pay and activate the full version.

I have seen this in lot of games... But I don't know where to start with.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html is what you're looking for

Comment: This is the help page for in-app products:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1072599 You can also find it in your Developer Console.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the [Google Play Billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html). Develop your game with all the modules and enable/disable the modules according to what the user has bought. In order to do this verification, [register products](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html) for your app that represents the module