# In app Billing in android app

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I know this question may be repeated before but unfortunately I do not  get any answer i needed from any related post. I am developing an app in which i could sell some products with a payment system , in this i want to integrate Google plays in app payment gateway ,I know how to integrate in app payment gateway

I tried this link

[How to connect playstore payment gateway inside app in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856343/how-to-connect-playstore-payment-gateway-inside-app-in-android)

Let me know whether we could change the price of the product through my app.

Comment: No you can not change the price of your product by your app...

Answer (score 0):

Think about it, if programmatically we could change the price of a product via the app, we could hack our way to get our customers to pay more than the actual cost. Which is completely incorrect. The administrator of the play console should have control on that, not the app.

May be if you can throw some light on `what you are trying to acheive you can get different solutions here`.